# Problems with Mendeley references in LaTeX

Tags: bibtex

I am writing my master thesis with LaTeX and using `mendeley` for the bibliography. Since yesterday I do have a problem: If a citation is already in my LaTeX file it compiles it, while if I have to add a new citation from my `mendeley` library, the result is `(?,?)`.

PS: This is the message I get in the folder with the `.bib` file

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
> (format=pdflatex 2012.6.30) 9 OCT 2014 12:51 entering extended mode
> restricted \write18 enabled. %&-line parsing enabled.
> **library.tex
>
> ! Emergency stop. <*> library.tex
>
> *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
> ```

pps: this is an example with an easy LaTeX file and two .bib entries (don't look at the bibliography file, that's why I added the two entries...)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{apacite} 
\title{test} 
\author{Bernardo Fiorini } 
\begin{document} \maketitle 
\section{Let's try} 
\lipsum \cite{Bang2009} 
\cite{Baumgartner2006}
 \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
 \bibliography{/Users/bernardofiorini/Documents/references.bib/library}
 \end{document}
```

ENTRIES THAT WORKS:

```
@article{Baumgartner2006, 
 author = {Baumgartner, Thomas and Esslen, Michaela and J\"{a}ncke, Lutz},
issn = {0167-8760}, 
 journal = {International Journal of Psychophysiology}, 
 month = apr, 
number = {1}, 
pages = {34--43}, 
publisher = {Elsevier}, 
title = {{From emotion perception to emotion experience: emotions evoked by pictures and classical music.}}, 
volume = {60}, year = {2006} 
}
```

ENTRIES THAT DOES NOT WORK:

```
@article{Bang2009, 
author = {Bang, Hyejin and Won, Doyeon and Kim, Yongjae}, 
journal = {Event Management}, pages = {69--81}, 
title = {{Motivations, Commitment, and Intentions to continue volunteering for sporting events}}, 
volume = {13}, 
year = {2009} 
}
```

Comment: (1) Wellcome to the site. (2) This is not much for us to attempt to debug your document. Please provide more data, preferably a minimal example, that is data we can copy and test on our systems as is without having to add anything.

Comment: How do you add citation to bib file? You copy it as BibTex entry?

Comment: The citations in the .bib file are automatically produced and created by Mendeley.

Comment: I tried with another file (University paper) I already used on Latex, and the result is the same: impossible to add new citations that are not already in the references list, while if I use citations already in the paper, then it works. It should be then a problem of Latex and not Mendeley, what do you think?

Comment: @daleif thanks for your help. How can I provide a minimal example? It works like that with whatever document or file I add on Mendeley and then try to cite it on Latex...

Comment: Start by preparing the smallest possible document that you think ought to work (this is often based on the `article` class). Prepare say a `.bib` file with just one entry, update your question with the minimal example and the small `bib` file then it is a lot easier for us to help. As it sits now we need real life crystal ball to predict what is going on in your end.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. The path looks odd since I left my .bib file in it, and added the two entries to be added in a sew .bib file, otherwise I did not know how to do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is not Mendeley, your problem is your outdated TeX/LaTeX-distribution.

In your given error message we can read:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
>   (format=pdflatex 2012.6.30) 9 OCT 2014 12:51 entering extended mode
>   restricted \write18 enabled. %&-line parsing enabled.

The current version of TeX Live is 2014.

Please update your system and then you should have no problems with compiling ...

Answer (score 1):

Longer comment, this works just fine

Compiled with `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`

BTW: It is not a good idea to use `title={{}}`, title casing should be left to the style to decide, just protect words (with a `{}` pair) that absolutely should not be in lower case. Even if the book is called *My Awesome Book* it is still up to your publisher to decide how book titles are to be formated.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytest.bib}
@article{Baumgartner2006, 
 author = {Baumgartner, Thomas and Esslen, Michaela and J\"{a}ncke, Lutz},
issn = {0167-8760}, 
 journal = {International Journal of Psychophysiology}, 
 month = apr, 
number = {1}, 
pages = {34--43}, 
publisher = {Elsevier}, 
title = {{From emotion perception to emotion experience: emotions evoked by pictures and classical music.}}, 
volume = {60}, year = {2006} 
}
@article{Bang2009, 
author = {Bang, Hyejin and Won, Doyeon and Kim, Yongjae}, 
journal = {Event Management}, pages = {69--81}, 
title = {{Motivations, Commitment, and Intentions to continue volunteering for sporting events}}, 
volume = {13}, 
year = {2009} 
} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{apacite} 
\title{test} 
\author{Bernardo Fiorini } 
\begin{document} \maketitle 
\section{Let's try} 
\lipsum \cite{Bang2009} 
\cite{Baumgartner2006}
 \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
 \bibliography{mytest}
 \end{document}
```